# Async unit tests are not visible in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, xunit

I use Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate, I wrote some unit test (I use xUnit 2.1.0.3179, it allow for this signature):

```
public async Task MyTest()
```

instead of standard unit test signature

```
public void MyTest()
```

but these unit tests are not visible in Visual Studio (code lens) and in Test Explorer. Of course I rebuild solution without any error :)

[image]

Is there any possibility to have the same feature like tests with standard signature? Maybe there is any VS extension?

Comment: Is this test running [in ASP.NET by any chance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799380/xunit-async-tests-shows-up-as-external-in-vs2015)?

Comment: I thought that xUnit tests weren't able to access CodeLens at all, hence no mention of them in CodeLens... or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you might've found a solution for this already, but I found your question while I was trying to fix my async unit test.  (Note: I'm using the latest Visual Studio 2015 Update 3).

```
   [TestMethod]
    public async Task GetVendors_ByRegionId_ReturnFilteredVendors()
    {
        // Arrange
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=server12345;Database=DB789;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
        var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        ILoggerFactory logFac = new LoggerFactory();
        ILogger<VendorRepository> loggerRepository = new Logger<VendorRepository>(logFac);
        IVendorRepository vendRepo = new VendorRepository(ctx, loggerRepository);

        // Act
        Task<List<Vendor>> resultTask = vendRepo.GetVendors(1);
        IList<Vendor> vendorList = await resultTask;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(vendorList);
        Assert.IsTrue(vendorList.Count > 10);
    }
```

Comment: The OP is using xUnit, you are using the built in unit test system.